# User creates an Item, deletes his account. undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When an User creates an item, attributes such as:

- user_name
- user_email
- user_crawl

and much much more are displayed through out the app.

Because this items are not `:dependent => :destroy` as soon a user destroys his account
the app brakes.

How can i hold on to that attributes when a user destroys his account ?

**Example**

```
:item belongs_to :user
:user has_many :items
```

An item has:

```
<%= item.user.id%>
<%= image_tag(item.user.avatar) %>
<%= item.user.crawl %>
```

> The Items will be shown even if the user is not existent. How can i
>   keep the attributes such as "name" "ID" "email" in the view. e.g.
>   "Item was created by TestUser", can i somehow keep that "TestUser"
>   string?

Comment: Can you give an example of what breaks when the user is deleted? I don't see why any of these things would be deleted unless they are part of the user model itself.

Comment: ??> If an user deletes his account, the where are the attributes stored ? He's deleted from the DB..

Comment: You can't have it deleted from the DB and keep it too.

Comment: Thats my problem :) how do i fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Soft deletion

To avoid that, usually, I won't delete user records, but rather just deactivate user's account with a soft delete that removes `user#password` and `user#activated_at`. That way, you're certain your database integrity is not compromised.

Of course, there may be privacy issues with this, so make sure that :

- only data absolutely necessary is kept (remove emails, address, phone number, etc)
- double check user won't receive any mails or something (removing email is a good way, you may also have an `unsubscribed` attribute anyway for registered users that don't want communication, so automatically set it for users that want to delete their account).

## Proxy model

An other option would be to group most vital data in an other model. You could have, for example :

```
User.has_one :vcard
User.has_many :items, through: :vcard

Item.belongs_to :vcard
Item.has_one :user, through :vcard

Vcard.belongs_to :user
Vcard.has_many :items
```

A `Vcard` would contain user `name`, `avatar` and `crawl` (and of course a `user_id` since it belongs to user).

Using that, you can entirely delete User, and Item is still related to a Vcard with relevant information. You should probably change avatar to some placeholder to be kind to an user that want to delete his account, though.

This solution is also nice to avoid having conditional validations in your user model.

Comment: The Soft Deletion sounds right.. Can i use [Acts_as_paranoid](https://github.com/goncalossilva/acts_as_paranoid) or is there a better solution ?

Comment: I usually only go with removing `confirmed_at` from devise user attributes, so that 1°) user can reactivate her account just by requesting new activation link, 2°) somebody can't create an other account using the same name (possibly impersonating someone) and of course 3°) it's considered inactive for auth purpose. If you use devise, you can use [more builtin behavior from #active_for_authentication?](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/520e2845aef33c7e69e9bd052964daf27719aaba/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L34), though.

Comment: Hey Olivier, can you join me on chat for a brief moment ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39446/rails-dev

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be delegating to the User model from Item. If the user no longer exists, naturally this will break. You can specify 'allow_nil' and it will merely return nil:

```
class Item
   delegates :name, :to => :user, :allow_nil => true, :prefix => true
end
```

If the user does not exists, then then calling `item.user_name` will return nil.

EDIT

If you want to keep that information, you should not delete the associated database record. You can add a `disabled` boolean column that deactivate the account, but the record will still exist so that data stays in the database.

Your users may be expecting their data to be purged

Comment: The Items will be shown even if the user is not existent. How can i keep the attributes such as "name" "ID" "email" in the view. e.g. "Item was created by TestUser", can i somehow keep that "TestUser" string?